# Convert json to dataframe in order of which column listed first in json file using spark/scala

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Im using **spark/scala** to transform my json into a dataframe.
For example, below is the json

[image]

I want my dataframe to print out the below in order (currently its printing in alphabetical order) [image]

Using terminal for transform:
`val df_in=spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json("/Users/testfile/tests.json")` and `df_in.show()`

When I run the above code it transforms the json file into a df but not in the order I want - Is there a way to print out **in order of columns listed first** in my json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can defined a schema and use it while reading the file.

```
val schema="FirstName STRING,LastName STRING,MiddleName STRING,username STRING,password STRING"

val df_in=spark.read.option("multiLine","true").schema(schema).json("/Users/testfile/tests.json")
```

If you specify the schema it avoids extra scan as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use select and choices of columns

```
df = df.select("FirstName", "LastName", "MiddleName", "username" "password").show()
```